# How to allow guest auth using Digits by twitter

Tags: android, twitter-digits

I am blocked while implementing Digits sign in with phone number into my Android app. Digits throws a strange error saying

> Your app may not allow guest auth. Please talk to us regarding upgrading your consumer key.
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 403 Forbidden